# vscode doesn't seem to activate my virtual python environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I have some python code that I wrote and have just installed vscode and starting to work with it.

the code is in home/user/code/dlS3BMC folder which has a env folder with my virtual environment.
I am using Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia cinnamon desktop, vscode 1.41.1

I open this folder in vscode.  ctrl+ shft+p and I see my virtual environment, I select it, but when I do which python in the terminal window it is still pointing to the system python /usr/bin/python

If I . env/bin/activate in the terminal everything works fine - I don't mind doing that but it would be nice if I didn't have to.

From the microsoft docs I think it is supposed to automatically activate the env, but it does not.  I have tried saving project after I activate, but when I close and open again, it is not activated.  Sorry I am very new to vscode at this stage and have just used sublime text editor to write my python code in the past.

Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 0):

ok, it seems it does not activate the virtual environment until you run the code either debug or simply run... when you run the code, I can see it activate the env.

TIL this.

Regards
Bill

Comment: If the terminal is open before you launch the Python extension -- which is done simply by opening Python code -- then there's no activation. If you create a new terminal after activating the extension then everything will work as expected.

Comment: This is really annoying when doing test-driven development. I have to re-select interpreter every time. Then extension is activated and then I see list of tests.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in VS Code (still... nearly 2 years later). If you would like to see it fixed, you can give [the VSCode Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105455) a "thumbsup". If it reaches 20 before Jan 10th, it'll be added to their development roadmap